# EditText not a "box"

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and Eclipse.  Why in my application does the EditText not show up as the traditional "box".  I tried doing it with both the designer and xml.  Instead, the EditText looks like an "underscore".  Thanks.

Comment: This is because you are using newer version of android in which this is the default theme you will have to style it as per your need if your application supports lower version run it to them you'll get your BOX back

Comment: Just change your theme based on your need. Ex:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: y are u posting same question again and again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669301/edittext-not-showing-as-a-box

Answer (score 3):

If by underscore you mean:

[image]

Instead of

[image]

Then you are seeing the new holo UI style. It is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

because use android 4.0 or style

change style or use a XML drawable for background